# How to maintain close VBA editor window when I open Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I' d like to know if Excel gives the possibility to maintain closed the windows inside VBA editor when I open again the same file.

I have a file excel with a macro

```
Public Sub CloseAllVBEWindows()

Dim wk As Workbook
Dim CodeWindow As Variant

For Each wk In Application.Workbooks
    If wk.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
       For Each CodeWindow In wk.VBProject.VBE.Windows
           If CodeWindow.Visible = True Then CodeWindow.Visible = False
       Next CodeWindow
    End If
Next wk

End Sub
```

when I run the macro inside the file, all the windows inside VBA correctly disappear.
Well, but when I re-open the same file I find again opened the same windows even if I have saved before the settings.

I don' t understand why because I have seen that if a user close manually the windows inside VBA editor, the next time that re-opens the file, the windows remain closed.

The macro would be done the same things ...

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the windows to be invisible, when it sounds like you want to close them.

Change this line `If CodeWindow.Visible = True Then CodeWindow.Visible = False`

To just: `CodeWindow.Close`